Oracle SQL Shift Differentiate
I have a request to identify records between two shifts.  Shift 1 begin at 7am - 6:59pm same day and shift 2 begin on 7pm - 6:59am the next day.  I can only write SQL cannot create function or procedure.  Could you please advice how I can go about accomplish this through SQL code. sample data
shift
Thank you in advance for your help/suggestion
classify records create between 7am - 6:59pm as shift 1
classify records created between 7pm - 6:59am the next day as shift 2
shift continue

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data (as text we can copy/paste and execute, not as images); your attempt at a solution; and the expected output for your sample data (again, as text not an image).

Subtract 7 hours from your time to get a normalised time and then calculate what fraction of the day has occurred in the time component of the normalised time. If it is less than half a day then it is the first shift, if it is half-or-greater then it is the second shift.
Something like this:
SELECT date_time,
       TO_CHAR(date_time - INTERVAL '7' HOUR, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS shift_date,
       FLOOR(
         (
           (date_time - INTERVAL '7' HOUR)
           - TRUNC(date_time - INTERVAL '7' HOUR)
         ) * 2
       ) + 1 AS shift_number
FROM   table_name

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (date_time) AS
SELECT DATE '2024-01-06' + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '1' HOUR
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24;

Outputs:



DATE_TIME
SHIFT_DATE
SHIFT_NUMBER




2024-01-06 00:00:00
2024-01-05
2


...
...
...


2024-01-06 06:00:00
2024-01-05
2


2024-01-06 07:00:00
2024-01-06
1


...
...
...


2024-01-06 18:00:00
2024-01-06
1


2024-01-06 19:00:00
2024-01-06
2


...
...
...


2024-01-06 23:00:00
2024-01-06
2



fiddle

Your solution gave me exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much for your help!
